# Conditional Solver in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-solver

i'm facing a new problem with my excel solver. Maybe someone can help me or provide a hint?

I wrote the following VBA to maximize the return of a portfolio of financial assets given a set of constraints:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Dim assetReturns As ListObject
Set assetReturns = ws.ListObjects("tblAssetReturns")

Dim numColumnsAssets As Long
numColumnsAssets = assetReturns.ListColumns.Count
    
Dim portfolioWeightsVector() As Variant
Dim activeCellAddress As Variant
Dim adjustableCellsAddress As String

activeCellAddress = ws.Range("noShortSale").Address

adjustableCellsAdress = activeCellAddress & ":" & Range(activeCellAddress).Offset(numColumnsAssets - 2, 0).Address

Range(adjustableCellsAdress).ClearContents

Solverreset

SolverOptions Precision:=0.000001, Iterations:=20, AssumeNonNeg:=True
SolverOk SetCell:="noShortSaleMean", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range(adjustableCellsAdress), Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

solverAdd CellRef:=Range(adjustableCellsAdress), relation:=1, FormulaText:=0.1
solverAdd CellRef:="noShortSaleWeightSum", relation:=2, FormulaText:=1

SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
```

I would like to add another constraint, where i want to limit the weight of each asset i of those assets (in adjustableCellsAdress), which reach the maximum of 10%, to a total of 80%. In other words, i have say 20 assets, where solver returns for 3 assets the maximum weight of 10%. I want to add another constraint to check that the sum of these 10%-asset-weights is smaller than 80%. So, a feasible combination in my example is 10%+10%+10%<80%, but if 9 assets reach 10%, this violates the additional constraint.
Given the code above, where/how can i add this sum-constraint in my VBA?

ADDENDUM:Well, I found a way around for the moment by using some stupid SUMIF blabla function so I can include this in my solver add but it's not so nice. I appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction how to include this in the solver constraints It would make my day shine

Thanks for your help, any ideas are appreciated..
Thomas

Comment: Instead of conjoining addresses as a string, it would be cleaner to create the range through the use of [Range.Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize). Like `Set adjustableCells = ws.Range("noShortSale").Resize(, assetReturns.ListColumns.Count - 2)`

Comment: @Toddleson Thanks a lot, yes, mine is not beautiful but it works at the moment. Thanks for the idea :-)